# How to loop rows and columns in pandas while replacing values with a constant increment

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, cumsum

I am trying to replace values in a dataframe by `0`. the first column I need to replace the 1st `3` values, the next column the 1st `6` values so on so forth increasing by `3` every time

```
a=np.array([133,124,156,189,132,176,189,192,100,120,130,140,150,50,70,133,124,156,189,132])
b = pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(10,2), columns= ['s','t'])
for columns in b:
    yy = 3
    for i in xrange(yy):
        b[columns][i] = 0 
    yy += 3
print b
```

the outcome is the following

```
      s    t
0     0    0
1     0    0
2     0    0
3   189  189
4   132  132
5   176  176
6   189  189
7   192  192
8   100  100
9   120  120
```

I am clearly missing something really simple, to make the loop replace `6` values instead of only `3` in column `t`, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need inicialize `yy=3` before loop:

```
yy = 3
for columns in b:
   for i in xrange(yy):
        b[columns][i] = 0 
    yy += 3
print b
```

`Python 3` solution:

```
yy = 3
for columns in b:
    for i in range(yy):
        b[columns][i] = 0 
    yy += 3

print (b)
     s    t
0    0    0
1    0    0
2    0    0
3  189    0
4  100    0
5  130    0
6  150   50
7   70  133
8  124  156
9  189  132
```

Another solution:

```
yy= 3

for i, col in enumerate(b.columns):
    b.ix[:i*yy+yy-1, col] = 0

print (b)
     s    t
0    0    0
1    0    0
2    0    0
3  189    0
4  100    0
5  130    0
6  150   50
7   70  133
8  124  156
9  189  132
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do it this way:

```
i = 1
for c in b.columns:
    b.ix[0 : 3*i-1, c] = 0
    i += 1
```

Demo:

```
In [86]: b = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(20, 4)), columns=list('abcd'))

In [87]: %paste
i = 1
for c in b.columns:
    b.ix[0 : 3*i-1, c] = 0
    i += 1
## -- End pasted text --

In [88]: b
Out[88]:
     a   b   c   d
0    0   0   0   0
1    0   0   0   0
2    0   0   0   0
3   10   0   0   0
4    8   0   0   0
5   49   0   0   0
6   55  48   0   0
7   99  43   0   0
8   63  29   0   0
9   61  65  74   0
10  15  29  41   0
11  79  88   3   0
12  91  74  11   4
13  56  71   6  79
14  15  65  46  81
15  81  42  60  24
16  71  57  95  18
17  53   4  80  15
18  42  55  84  11
19  26  80  67  59
```